# How can I set style to propertgrid rows?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a propertygrid with 10 items(for example).

I want set back color for even items(2,4,6,8,10) to red & for odd items(1,3,5,7,9) to blue.
How can I it ?

Similar in set BackColor in Appearence in AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle property in Datagridview.